# How can i access the char array inside of an std::string?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdstring

I was given a task to write a file system in Linux that simulates a storage device as a file.

One of the functions I was given needs to read data inside a "file". To do so I have a function that's supposed to return an `std::string`.

How can I read the data out of the file with the following function
directly into an `std::string`?

```
void read(int addr, int size, char *ans)
```

Is there a way to pass the char array inside of an `std::string` as a parameter to this function?
All of the methods and member functions I have encountered so far only return `const char*` which doesn't work in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conventional way of doing this is to pass a pointer to the string’s first character. This is guaranteed to work because the standard guarantees that the characters inside a `std::basic_string` are stored contiguously ([[basic.string]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.classes#basic.string-2)).

Thus,

```
read(addr, str.size(), & str[0]);
```

works, *but only if you have previously resized the string to a non-zero size*. Additionally, your `read` function doesn’t tell you *how many* characters were read. There needs to be some functionality in your IO API to tell you this.

Comment: since c++17 [`str.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) is a viable option.

Answer (score -3):

Actually, it is bad idea to do so, as then `std::string` class doesn't know, how many characters were inserted. It is much better to create local buffer `std::array<char, 256> buf`, pass it to function, and then put it into `std::string` using `std::string(buf.data, buf.size())`.

Comment: That doesn’t solve the problem. The `read` function needs to *tell* you how many characters were inserted. The signature given by OP doesn’t do that, but maybe another function does. Anyway, there’s no reason not to insert directly into a string.